# track button input in android

Tags: android, button, textview

[image]I want to track the input from a button and display it on the screen. For example I have a basic layout that has 4 buttons and a text view. the text view starts at 10 and each button changes the value of 10 by + or - 1, and + or - 5. I want a text view to show the changes on screen. I already have a text view for the 10 that does change as the buttons are pressed but I want another textview to show what buttons have been pressed already. I have no idea how to start this and need some input.

```
@Override public void onClick(View v) 
{ String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString(); 
 btnPressedTV.append(text);
```

This is the code that i put in, given by codemagic. I want the new textview to show the history of the values that 20 was. for example if the textview that is 20 changes to 18, then 15, then 22, then 45 I want the btnPressedTV to show those values.

Comment: Could You share Your code? Please, provide more specific description? You're able to change one text views content, but not able to change another ones?

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString();  // cast the   
    View to a Button and get the text
    btnPressedTV.append(text);   // insert whatever formatting you  
    want
    }
This is what codemagic provided, it is the only start that I have. I want to have a textbox below each texbox with '20' already in it that, when the total of 20 changes, it will show the log of the changes. I have the code working that changes 20 up and down based on the button pressed. I want to show in a new textview the history of the previous values.

Comment: whoever keeps flagging my post, I posted a screenshot to give an idea of what I needed help with and i said that I was looking for a place to start because i wasnt sure. stop flagging stuff if you dont have an answer, other people may be willing to help even if you are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want another textview to show what buttons have been pressed already

This is a rather unclear question which makes it hard to answer. However, if you want the name of the `Button` pressed then you simply create your other `TextView`, say `btnPressedTV` then use the `getText()` method in your `onClick()` to display the `Button` clicked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String text = ((Button)v).getText().toString();  // cast the View to a Button and get the text
    btnPressedTV.append(text);   // insert whatever formatting you want
}
```

Comment: Its tough to explain, your right. basically what I would like to have is a text view that would show the past totals. so if the main text view is 10 and I press one, then the main text view goes to 11 and the new text view shows 11. then if I press 1 again the main text view changes to 12 and the new text view now shows 11 and 12 right below it so you can see what the past totals were. I dont know if that clears it up any.

Comment: So have an `int` variable that keeps track of the totals and display it each time. I'm not sure what else I can tell you without seeing what you have and where the problem is.

Comment: I dont actually have anything yet other then my main layout and activity that keeps track of the main change of the 10. I wasnt sure where to start. So in my main activity all I need to do is insert what you have posted for each button?

Comment: I don't know since I'm not sure I exactly get you. You can use on `onClick()` for all of them if they do almost the same thing. What I wrote above will get the text of the `Button` that was clicked and add it to the `TextView`.

Comment: I added a screenshot for reference. the buttons all work to change the value of the 20 in the text box. I want to add another text view below the 20 that will show what the values have been. for example if I press +5, then -1, then +1, I want it to show each value in a running list

Comment: I already have a method that is onClick(View v) for rolling dice, can I use onClick(View a) or any other variable? it is giving me an error even when I replaced the v with an a

Comment: looking back over this, does your code make it so it displays the button clicked? I want it to show the past totals. so if button 5 was clicked and the total was 25, and then -1 clicked so it is now 24, that it shows in the new textview 25 and then 24 under it